# Auto suggest feature query is taking too much time after adding index in column oracle

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

I know this question has been asked several time but i haven't got the solution yet and I am no expert in database .

So my requirement is to implement the auto suggest feature , for which I have written query which is extracting data from million of rows from specific table . For that purpose I have written a query using like operator which is taking hell lot of time can you please advice how to optimize the query in oracle.

**Note-:**`Index has been added to name column`

Query

```
SELECT distinct name,designator 
FROM xyz info 
WHERE name LIKE UPPER ( 'a%' ) 
and ROWNUM <= 20 
ORDER BY name
```

Below the execution plan image

[image]

Comment: Show us the execution plan (**Edit** your question Plain text please, no screen shots). Also: the `ROWNUM <= 20` isn't going to work the way you think it is: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  please see the above execution plan. i don't have idea to get execution plan on plain text by using query so that's why i have pasted the execution plan image

Comment: The plan shows a different where condition than your question. The plan shows that you are using `upper(name) like 'A%'` (**not** `name like upper('a%')`) which will **not** use an index on `name`. You will need to create an index on `upper(name)` not `name`. And the next time, please post the plain text version of the execution plan. That graphical thing usually hides too many details.

Comment: As "no_name_horse" said in case you use  (UPPER(NAME)) you will have to create an index on UPPER(NAME). "Gordon Linoff"'s suggestion also is a good one, I would implement both.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest that you use a composite index, `(name, designator)` instead of a single column index.

Second, is the `distinct` really necessary?  That is, do you have duplicates in the table?  If so, I would fix the duplicates and use:

```
SELECT name, designator 
FROM xyz info 
WHERE name LIKE UPPER ( 'a%' ) and ROWNUM <= 20 
ORDER BY name;
```